# Selecting a word and shows tooltip in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, tooltip, uitextview, textkit

I would like to implement the Medium iOS App like effect for **tapping highlight and shows tooltip**.

---

[image: Medium Highlight Tooltip]

---

I have been researching on `Text Kit` and some other stackoverflow questions have some thoughts on it, please also suggest what's the better alternative to this.

Scenario:

1. Static Text pre-defined
2. Shows highlights in several words or phrases

Solution thoughts:

1. Use `UITextView` for storing text
2. Use attributed string for text content
3. Showing background color using `NSBackgroundColorAttributedName`
4. Detect the selection by `layoutManager.characterIndexForPoint(...)`
5. Shows tooltip next to the selection
6. Shows tooltip using one of these pods `AMPopTip`, `CMPopTipView`, `EasyTipView`

Right now, I am not able to select the word and shows the tooltip just next to it. Any tier of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Here is a way to Highlight text.

Create an IBOutlet named `myLabel`

In `ViewDidLoad` type

```
let yourString = "This is how you highlight text"
myLabel.text = yourString

let malleableString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: yourString)

let numberOfCharactersToHighlight = 5
let startingIndex = 1
malleableString.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: .magenta, range: NSRange(location: startingIndex, length: numberOfCharactersToHighlight))

myLabel.attributedText = malleableString
```